# Is it possible to deploy a background Function "myBgFunctionInProjectB" in "project-b" and triggered by my topic "my-topic-project-a" from "project-a"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

It's possible to create a topic *"my-topic-project-a"* in project *"project-a"* so that it can be publicly visible (this is done by setting the role *"pub/sub subscriber"* to *"allUsers"* on it).
Then from project *"project-b"* I can create a subscription to *"my-topic-project-a"*  and read the events from *"my-topic-project-a"*. This is done using the following gcloud commands:
(these commands are executed on project "project-b")

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create subscription-to-my-topic-project-a --topic projects/project-a/topics/my-topic-project-a
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull subscription-to-my-topic-project-a --auto-ack
```

So ok this is possible when creating a subscription in "project-b" linked to "my-topic-project-a" in "project-a".

**In my use case I would like to be able to deploy a background function "myBgFunctionInProjectB" in "project-b" and triggered by my topic "my-topic-project-a" from "project-a"**

But ... this doesn't seem to be possible since gcloud CLI is not happy when you provide the full topic name while deploying the cloud function:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy myBgFunctionInProjectB --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-topic projects/project-a/topics/my-topic-project-a --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) argument --trigger-topic: Invalid value 'projects/project-a/topics/my-topic-project-a': Topic must contain only Latin letters (lower- or upper-case), digits and the characters - + . _ ~ %. It must start with a letter and be from 3 to 255 characters long.
```

is there a way to achieve that or this is actually not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that is not actually possible to do this. I have found it by checking it in 2 different ways:

- If you try to create a function through [the API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/create), you will need to fill the location where you want to run this, for example, `projects/PROJECT_FOR_FUNCTION/locations/PREFERRED-LOCATION`, and then, provide a request body, like this one:

> {
>
> "eventTrigger": {
>
> "resource": "projects/PROJECT_FOR_TOPIC/topics/YOUR_TOPIC",
>
> "eventType": "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
>
> },
>
> "name":
>   "projects/PROJECT_FOR_FUNCTION/locations/PREFERRED-LOCATION/functions/NAME_FOR_FUNTION
>
> }

This will result in a 400 error code, with a message saying:

> {
>
> "field": "event_trigger.resource",
>
> "description": "Topic must be in the same project as function."
>
> }

It will also say that you missed the source code, but, nonetheless, the API already shows that this is not possible.

- There is an already [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/62373846) in the Public Issue Tracker for this very same issue. Bear in mind that there is no ETA for it.

I also tried to do this from `gcloud`, as you tried. I obviously had the same result. I then tried to remove the `projects/project-a/topics/` bit from my command, but this creates a new topic in the same project that you create the function, so, it's not what you want.

Comment: ok, thanks. I wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything before moving to another solution